# Сумма последовательности через рекурсию на JS

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Нужно найти сумму последовательности именно через рекурсию. Проблема заключается в следующем.
Приведенный ниже код отлично работает, в отладчике никаких проблем нет, показывает результат

```js
const sequenceSum = (from, to) => {
  if (from > to) return sequenceSum(to, from);
  if (from === to) return from;
  return from + sequenceSum(from + 1, to);
}

console.log(sequenceSum(2, 6));
```

Если же я пишу то же самое, но прошу пользователя ввести числа с помощью prompt, то в отладчике получаю ошибку Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, результат не вижу.

```js
let num1 = prompt('Enter first number', );
let num2 = prompt('Enter second number', );

const sequenceSum = (from, to) => {
  if (from > to) return sequenceSum(to, from);
  if (from === to) return from;
  return from + sequenceSum(from + 1, to);
}

console.log(sequenceSum(num1, num2));
```

Почему? Где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: промпт дает строку, приведите к числу...

Comment: Очень несложно было, большое спасибо!

Comment: Почему возникает именно такая ошибка?

Comment: не знаю, я не стал разбираться )

Comment: такая ошибка потому что происходит конкатенация строк (к примеру: `'2' + 1 = '21', '4'`), '21' > '4'  ? `true` => `sequenceSum('21', '4')` и всё по новой до бесконечности

Comment: Понял, спасибо!